# Is there a way to run a command on changes in a git commit?

Tags: git, shell

So the problem is: I did a huge search and replace with "", I then tweaked a few of the changes manually, only to realize I forgot to include a \n in the regex i searched for, and now have a huge commit which adds empty new lines in many places. I imagine (read: hope) there must be some way to rewrite a commit and replace \n\n with \n in the changes, but can't figure out how.

Comment: `git reset --soft HEAD^`, run your replacement, `git add -u && git commit`. Or just: run replacement, `git add -u && git commit --amend`. git log or git show to get the changes of a commit.

Comment: Is your question how to rewrite the commit or how to find which files have changed in the commit? Or how to do the actual replacement? It's unclear which part of your story is the problem.

Comment: @knittl I want to avoid doing the replacement again as I don't want to have to redo the manual changes afterwards. I know how to find files changed in a commit and amend. What I want is to run the replacement only on the actual changes, not just the files changed. So if I have added an empty new line in the file I want to replace that, but not the other empty new lines in the file.

Comment: Just a guess, but if "I then tweaked a few of the changes manually" is on the low side (comparatively), the simplest course of action without a perfect automated script, would be to redo the replacement correctly and commit it, and then redo those "few" manual changes which you should be able to isolate by comparing the new commit from the original commit- anything that has more than a newline difference is a manual change you need to repeat. (In fact, if I were to automate it, those steps might be where I'd start...)

Comment: @TTT: I guess you’re right. Would be interesting to know if there’s a way to do what I’m asking anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There indeed exists an artistic solution for this:
Let's say your faulty commit hash was hashA and hash of commit before this was hasB, then run the following:

`git diff hashB..hashA | sed "/^+$/d" | git apply`

This will create a diff patch, remove empty lines and re-apply it.